# ASP.NET MVC: Get values of a many to many table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

- I have a table '**Menus**' containing the
  names of the menus of the restaurant.

  - I also have a table '**Ingredients**'
    containing the ingredients that are
    available to the menus.

I don't have any trouble getting the values out of the 'Menus' table into an IQueryable class (PropAllMenus)

```
Public Class PropAllMenus
Private _MenuID As Integer
Public Property MenuID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _MenuID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _MenuID = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _Name As String
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _DaypartID As Integer
Public Property DaypartID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _DaypartID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _DaypartID = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I just use this code in the DBRepository class

```
Public Function ListAllMenus() As IQueryable(Of PropAllMenus) Implements IDBRepository.ListAllMenus

    Dim result = From p In _db.Menus Select New PropAllMenus With {.MenuID = p.MenuID, .Name = p.Name}
    Return result

End Function
```

This works fine.

- Now, i also have a many to many
  table '**MenuIngredients**' containing
  the Id's of ingredients that belong
  to a menu.

However, i don't know what steps i should take to:

1. Query the DB with a LINQ query to
   get a LIST of MENU NAMES with all
   their INGREDIENTS
2. fill up a new
   IQuerable(of...) class so i can pass
   it to my view

I tried using a property of type array (that contained the ingredients of a menu) but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

YOu just need to add a partial class to your current Menu class like this:

```
public partial class Books
    public property IEnumerable< Ingredient > Ingredients
     get

            return me. MenuIngredients.Select( function (mi) mi.Ingredient);
     end get

    end Property

    public sub AddIngredient( i as Ingredient )
    //do the logic here
    End Sub

    public sub AddIngredient( i as Ingredient )
    //do the logic here
    End Sub

    End
```

This then would include the ingredients in to your menu class